# REST client created Drupal user unable to login

Tags: rest, authentication, drupal-7

I am experimenting with remotely creating users via an [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo).

The user is successfully created on my Drupal-7 site but when I attempt to log the user in, I get the standard following error:

> Sorry, unrecognized username or password. Have you forgotten your password?

Below is a screenshot of  my REST client settings:
[image]

Comment: can you show the callback that receives the request?

Comment: Were you ever able to fix this problem? I'm working on a Drupal site myself (backend for an Android app), and I ran into the exact same problem as you. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109418/creating-a-user-using-services-results-in-user-not-being-able-authenticate-using

Comment: An addition to my comment above for those that ran into the same problem, please refer to this issue report: https://drupal.org/node/2198005

Answer (score 0):

Use the url

http://www.mysite.com/app/service/user/login

And make sure you have enabled the user login in Drupal's backend on services configuration.

Comment: Thank you but I haven't been very clear. At the moment, I am not attempting to login via services. What I was referring to was creating the user via services and then trying to log in to the site manually. The user exists but the login attempt is rejected.

Comment: are you able to login through services?

Answer (score 0):

Try

http://www.mysite.com/my_services/user/login

while my_services is your endpoint name defined in  7 service module

You may also use firefox poster
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/

If the login is successful, as i remember it will return "1" or "you are already logined"

session authentication seems also is needed to be abled

And also may sure "username" and "password" two parameters are necessary

'username=' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(pass)